# netty: WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline

Tags: java, server, netty, nio

I wrote service for my client to deal with multiple client it was working fine but last few days load of clients has been increased and now server code is generating exception and I am failing to understand what is it happening.

My code is:

```
    public void run() throws Exception {

    //System.setProperty("org.jboss.netty.epollBugWorkaround", "true");
    EventLoopGroup bossPool = new NioEventLoopGroup(BOSS_THREADS);
    EventLoopGroup workerPool = new NioEventLoopGroup(MAX_WORKER_THREADS);

    try {

        ServerBootstrap boot = new ServerBootstrap();
        boot.group(bossPool, workerPool);
        boot.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        boot.childHandler(new Pipeline());
        boot.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
        boot.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        boot.option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
        boot.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 6000);
        boot.option(ChannelOption.SO_TIMEOUT, 6);
        boot.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 2048);

        //System.out.println("Server started listening at port : " + port);
        boot.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } finally {
        workerPool.shutdownGracefully();
        bossPool.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Pipeline code is:

```
    public class Pipeline extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        // ch.pipeline().addLast("joiner", new JoinRequest());
        ch.pipeline().addLast("decoder", new ByteArrayDecoder());
        ch.pipeline().addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
        ch.pipeline().addLast("myHelper", new RequestHandler());
       }
    }
```

and here is detailed error log I am getting on daily basis:

```
1006465:54:21:10-16-03-2017Mar 16, 2017 10:21:54 AM         io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext exceptionCaught
WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doReadMessages(NioServerSocketChannel.java:135)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:69)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:471)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:385)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:351)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1412)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:280)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:877)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1706)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1661)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:126)

com.idea.builders.RequestHandler oprationSelector
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.dat (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.idea.builders.RequestHandler.oprationSelector(RequestHandler.java:175)
    at com.idea.builders.RequestHandler.messageReceived(RequestHandler.java:97)
    at com.idea.builders.RequestHandler.messageReceived(RequestHandler.java:35)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    at io.netty.channel.PausableChannelEventExecutor.invokeChannelRead(PausableChannelEventExecutor.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:389)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    at io.netty.channel.PausableChannelEventExecutor.invokeChannelRead(PausableChannelEventExecutor.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:389)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:956)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:127)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:471)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:385)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:351)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1412)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:280)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:877)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1706)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1661)
    at io.netty.util.internal.chmv8.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:126)

Mar 16, 2017 10:21:54 AM com.idea.builders.RequestHandler oprationSelector
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.dat (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.idea.builders.RequestHandler.oprationSelector(RequestHandler.java:175)
    at com.idea.builders.RequestHandler.messageReceived(RequestHandler.java:97)
    at com.idea.builders.RequestHandler.messageReceived(RequestHandler.java:35)
```

What should I do I have to restart my server on daily basis?

Comment: Make sure you close any files you open, this error is because you have too many file handles open on the system, are you making sure to kill any children threads once the clients disconnect?

Comment: Yes each thread is killed and files are also closing.

Comment: What OS are you on ?

Comment: Linux Red Hat 5.4

Comment: show the RequestHandler

Answer (score 1):

You should override `exceptionCaught` method in one of your handlers.

The message means that netty caugth exception but you didn't handle it in any of your handlers. Exceptions just reach the last pipeline handler and disappear. You probably should handle it in your request handler.

And yes close all streams after you finish working with files. And also you should release sockets and other resources on exceptions or unregistered events.